# Using Ros together with Unreal engine

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Guys,

I am thinking about switching from Gazebo to Unreal engine. Are Here any users who tried this ? And are there any Plugins that will Ros and Unreal Work together ?

Actual i just need a Turtlebot in Unreal and all camera data from depth and RGB Image.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/305087/using-ros-together-with-unreal-engine/) by [Baumboon](https://answers.ros.org/users/32033/baumboon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 206 on 2018-10-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[code-iai/ROSIntegration](https://github.com/code-iai/ROSIntegration) seems highly relevant.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1